# How to change the front of title when mouse over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button here and what I want is when mouseover this button, it will show some text automatically.

[image]

I use title to achieve this.

The HTML code is:

```
 <oj-buttonset-one id="splitDualYButtonSet" value="{{dualY}}" on-value-changed="[[updateDualY]]" title = "split">
            <!-- ko foreach: dualYOptions -->
            <oj-option value="[[value]]"><span data-bind="text:label"></span></oj-option>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </oj-buttonset-one>
```

when mouseover the button it will show "split" but now the front is too small. How to change the style of the title?

Thanks!

Comment: The format of the standard tooltip is determined by the browser/OS at a level below JS has access to. If you want to have control of that tooltip, you would need to use a tooltip library in HTML/JS

Comment: Check out some of the free JS frameworks out there that can do this with minimal fuss, I recommend jQuery UI and its tooltip widget: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ the beauty is that you dont need to include the entire framework, just pick what you need and include it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script >
        function hitMe() {
            document.getElementById("hello").innerText="yoo";
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="hello" onmouseover="hitMe()" >Yes</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add function in your controller and you can change the variable value from it